# Magento 1 and 2 SQL Select Count of picture of all SKUs?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.7, database, select

We are in the final steps to migrate from 1 to 2. Now we found that some picture got lost.

Is there a way to select all SKUs and their picture counts like:

```
SKU    Count
123    2
234    6
345    2
```

In Magento 1 and Magento 2 Mysql backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your Magento install does not use a prefix

on M1, you may try:

```
select count(*),c.sku from catalog_product_entity_media_gallery as i
left join catalog_product_entity as c on c.entity_id=i.entity_id
group by c.sku;
```

on M2, you may try:

```
select count(*),c.sku from catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value as i
left join catalog_product_entity as c on c.entity_id=i.entity_id
group by c.sku;
```

if your Magento install uses a prefix, let say test_ is your prefix

on M1, you may try:

```
select count(*),c.sku from test_catalog_product_entity_media_gallery as i
left join test_catalog_product_entity as c on c.entity_id=i.entity_id
group by c.sku;
```

on M2, you may try:

```
select count(*),c.sku from test_catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value as i
left join test_catalog_product_entity as c on c.entity_id=i.entity_id
group by c.sku;
```

to check the prefix of your magento install, you may open the file:

```
 app/etc/local.xml on Magento 1 and look for <table_prefix>  

and app/etc/env.php on Magento 2 and look for 'table_prefix' =>
```

Comment: Thanx so much, that worked well.